# sticky bootstrap footer overlaping content of page in responsive

Tags: responsive, sticky-footer

.....

```
    <div class="container">
    ......
    </div>
    </div> <!-- End -Wrap -->
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="container">
                ....
          </div>



html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  position: relative;

}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[![IN responsive (overlapping)][1]][1]
    [![in web page][2]][2]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/itr4Y.png
  [2]: https://i.stac
```

k.imgur.com/8OXpa.png

I have add screenshots.It is working in web pages but overlapping is responsive.Is it important to give the height of the footer.