# sticky footer overlapping the content during responsive

Tags: sticky-footer

```
        <body>
    <section>
.....
    </section>
    <footer>
    </footer>
    </body>

    footer{position:absolute;bottom:0}
section{position:relative}
```

I was making footer sticky in bottom.It is working fine in web. But see in responsive device,footer is overlapping the section part. I saw many example,There is mention height.Is it important to give height to footer,if yes then why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sticky bootstrap footer overlaping content of page in responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451425/sticky-bootstrap-footer-overlaping-content-of-page-in-responsive)

Comment: Please don't duplicate your questions.